# Chrome flattens Z-translated elements when opacity is applied

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transforms

[image]

Do you know what is chrome's reason for this? Is there a remedy?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body style="perspective:500px">
  
  
    <div style="
            width:40px; 
            height:40px; 
            background: green; 
            padding: 30px; 
            transform: rotateY(50deg); 
            transform-style: preserve-3d">
        <div style="
                transform: translateZ(60px)">
            content
        </div>
    </div>
  
  
  
    <hr style="margin: 40px 0">
  
  
  
    <div style="
              opacity: .5;
              width:40px; 
              height:40px; 
              background: green; 
              padding: 30px; 
              transform: rotateY(50deg); 
              transform-style: preserve-3d">
        <div style="
                transform: translateZ(60px)">
            content
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: do you use  -webkit-transform for safari ??

Comment: @noni nope, just this exact code.

Comment: try  transform: rotateY(50deg); -ms-transform: rotateY(50deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(50deg);

Comment: @noni same. Why would you expect anything different with that

Comment: because some time prefixes resolve the issue does you using  normalize css ?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem on placeholder from angular-material `translate3d` its ok on Firefox but is blurred on Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using [opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) with a value other than `1` places the element in a new
> [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).

This causes the flattening under browsers which are respecting the [new specification](https://css-tricks.com/things-watch-working-css-3d/#article-header-id-4).

We can use a wrapper element to set the `opcaity` (this element can be the one with the main `perspective` property as well depending on what we need):

```html
<div style="perspective:500px">
    <div style="perspective:inherit;opacity:.5">
        <div style="
            width:40px;
            height:40px;
            background: green;
            padding: 30px;
            transform: rotateY(50deg);
            transform-style: preserve-3d
        ">
            <div style="transform: translateZ(60px)">
                content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I downvoted because this does not resolve the issue, the whole 3D scene is now transparent. What if you want to make only one specific object in the 3D scene transparent, but not others? For example, suppose you put two green squares with "content" in them, and you want only one to be transparent, but not the other? This solution won't work.

Comment: Thank you for down voting and adding a comment with it! You are right. The image in the question is confusing. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I think the image in the question was confusing for you as well. So I updated the answer again.

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is what should happen as per standards:

> A value of preserve-3d for transform-style establishes a stacking context.
>
> The following CSS property values require the user agent to create a
>   flattened representation of the descendant elements before they can be
>   applied, and therefore override the behavior of transform-style:
>   preserve-3d:
>
> overflow: any value other than ‘visible’
>
> **opacity: any value other than 1.**
>
> filter: any value other than ‘none’.

[w3c spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-transforms-20120228/#transform-style)

Comment: This is absolutely horrible. Imagine if in Unreal engine or in Unity you applied opacity to an object, and it became flat like paper. People would not have it.