# Transform: translateZ only applying after transition has finished

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

Have I ran into an edge case that causes a rendering bug, or have I written some terrible CSS?

To replicate this, I've written the following demo:

The `body` element nests a `square` div that has a `span` child containing some text.

```html
<div class="square">
    <span>hello</span>
</div>
```

The `body` element controls the `perspective` attribute so that `translateZ` can work, but for some reason, this prop only triggers after the hover animation is done playing.

```css
* {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 500px;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    perspective: 1000px;
}

.square {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 500ms;
}

body:hover .square {
    bottom: 300px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.square span {
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    transform: translateZ(45px);
}
```

I've tested this example in Edge, Chrome, and Firefox so far and all have the same results, so I'm really wondering what I'm doing wrong here. Here's the link to the [codepen](https://codepen.io/SoloMDFK/pen/dyQMVgW?editors=1100).

To further understand the problem I've also attached a gif to showcase the problem even further.

[image: demo]

Notice how the `span` text that is translated on the Z axis jumps to its property of `transform: translateZ(45px)` just after the transition has ended. This effect can be noticed even better by changing the value of pixels that the `span` is translated by.

I'd really like to know what's happening and how can I prevent this. Thank you!

Comment: In this case it's a quirky interaction between `opacity` and `transform-style: preserve-3d`.  All opacity besides 1 will cause the render stack to flatten. This [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44824807/chrome-flattens-z-translated-elements-when-opacity-is-applied) goes into more details. You might get away with lifting the opacity rules to a parent wrapper and setting the opacity and perspective rules there.

Answer (score 0):

Add `.square { perspective: 1000px; }` - this will solve the problem.
And to improve animation performance, I recommend animating `transform` instead `bottom`, and adding `.square { will-change: transform, opacity; }`.

```css
* {
  /* bad idea to set it to all... */
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 500px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.square {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  transform: translateY(300px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: transform .5s, opacity .5s;
  perspective: 1000px;
  will-change: transform, opacity;
}

body:hover .square {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}


.square span {
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  transform: translateZ(400px);
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
  <span>hello</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The animation might be more performant, but this sadly doesn't solve the issue. Adding ```will-change: opacity``` to the ```square``` element just disregards the ```transform``` property of the ```span``` child. Before, the translated ```span``` at least jumped into its desired position after the transition was done; Adding the ```will-change``` property just flattens this ```span``` now.

Comment: I'm sorry I must have misunderstood the question. Updated my answer. Hope this helps you!